# C# MySql проблема подключения хранимой процедуры с dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql

Добрый вечер господа, данные хранимой процедуры не выводятся на datagridview.

Вот код хранимой процедуры на mysql:

```
SELECT local, SUM(Свободен), SUM(Занят), SUM(Отдих)
FROM (
SELECT local.locations AS local,
CASE car_stat_loc.id_status WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Свободен,
CASE car_stat_loc.id_status WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Занят,
CASE car_stat_loc.id_status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Отдих
FROM local, car_stat_loc
WHERE local.id_loc = car_stat_loc.id_status
) AS a
GROUP BY local
ORDER BY local
```

Вот код вызова на C#:

```
private void dataGridView3_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        connect.Open();
        MySqlCommand camd = connect.CreateCommand();
        camd.CommandText = "my_pr2";
        camd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        MySqlDataReader rez;
        rez = camd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        dataGridView3.DataSource = rez;
        camd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
    }
```

как выводить данные из хранимой процедуры на datagridview ?

Comment: `camd.ExecuteNonQuery();` ? `dataGridView1.DataBind();`

Comment: вместо camd.ExecuteNonQuery();  надо было надо было dataGridView3.DataBind(); ?

Comment: Ну во-первых это запрос, а не процедура. Во-вторых, зачем там обрамляющий запрос? группируйте и суммируйте сразу.

Comment: я проверю ваш вариант но скажите своё мнение насчёт этого вот ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921609/8176519

Answer (score 0):

```
      connect.Open();   
      using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
      {
         cmd.Connection = connect;
         using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
         {
           cmd.CommandText = @"EXEC my_pr2"; //Убедитесь что процедура создана и имя соответствующие, если не уверены вставьте полный запрос 
           dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
           dataGridView3.ItemsSource = dt;
          }
      }  
     connect.Close();
```

Connect тоже лучше в `using` взять, тогда не нужно будет его закрывать. Например :

```
using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(/* строка подключения */)) 
{
    //тут код
}
```

Comment: на англоязычной версии сайта предложили вариант создать класс и потом подключать его вот ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921609/8176519